# Azure function gives "The 'code' query parameter provided in the HTTP request did not match the expected value."

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am developing logic app in azure portal with azure function app.Logic app gives randomly code query parameter invalid error for function .
When ever error occurred i have to clone the logic app is there any permanent solution for this error.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for reporting - I've raised this issue with the Functions team to investigate.

Comment: @jeffhollan any update ?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this with a generic web hook function. The workaround I found was:

1. Go to the Function app page in the Azure portal
2. Select your app - You should see the menu with options "Develop", "Integrate", "Manage" and "Monitor"
3. Select "Manage"
4. There are two groups of keys - Function keys and Admin keys. The default Admin key was being used, so I changed the "code" parameter in my query to use the default Function key.

If that still doesn't work, you might want to try renewing the keys or adding a new one.

Comment: It does not help if you are using it in a logic app because you do not set function url but you refer to it by subscription/resourcegroup and so on

Answer (score 2):

Goto yourfunction->manage->functionkey->default -click on the copy link under actions

Just appending code

https://{functionappName}.azurewebsites.net/api/{functionName}?code={defaultfunctionkey}

Comment: why it requires code ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi this workaround worked for me

- in your logic app replace the AzureFunctionCall activity with the HTTP activity
- method POST
- url: https://FUNCTION_CONTAINER.azurewebsites.net/api/FUNCTION_NAME?code=DEFAULT_FUNCTION_KEY
- same body
- content-type application/json

Hope it helps