# Error invoking Function App from Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I did an update to the function, and now am getting this error in the Logic App. There's no entry in the Function App log.

```
{
  "Message": "The 'code' query parameter provided in the HTTP request did not match the expected value."
}
```

I've seen in other discussions hints about refreshing keys, but they all discuss the old portal. What is the current solution to solving this disconnect between Logic Apps and Functions?

Comment: Unfortunately, this issue doesn't seem resolved by Microsoft. However, there is one workaround. Please find my response in the https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f8479818-cfaa-4415-9c06-f72c897d0849/using-azure-functions-with-logic-apps-error-the-code-query-parameter-provided-in-the-http?forum=AzureFunctions thread (answered as NirmanD). This should work in most cases. Remember, its just a workaround, and Microsoft is yet to provide a permanent solution to this.

Comment: I believe this message is shown, when the key to invoke the function is invalid, which may happen after updating the function. Please try to open/re-save the Logic App, and it should retrieve a new key from function and fix the issue.

Comment: Try my suggestion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44152852/3959304

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a ticket to MSFT and received this reply:

Edit the logic app.
Select the “Code View”
Traverse through to find this function
In that there will line something like
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
Update this to 
"contentVersion": "1.1.1.1"

Following these steps resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Did not help, I also created a new function and got the same error

Comment: also a new logic app using the new function and the same error