# Azure Function Generic Webhook

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Using Visual Studio 2017, I created a Function App with a Generic WebHook:

```
public static class FunctionWebHook
    {
        [FunctionName("FunctionWebHook")]
        public static async Task<object> Run([HttpTrigger(WebHookType = "genericJson")]HttpRequestMessage request, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"Webhook was triggered!");

            string jsonContent = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            log.Info(jsonContent);

            return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
    }
```

The code is little more than the default template.  I deployed this to my Azure account and tried to invoke it.  I used the 'Get function url' link on the portal to get the correct URL, this included both the code and clientId parameters.  When I try to POST JSON to the function (with content type set to application/json) I receive a 400 Bad Request:

```
{"Message":"The 'code' query parameter provided in the HTTP request did not match the expected value."}
```

I've check the code parameter and it is correct.  I've also re-created the Function App several times, however I continue to receive the error.  When I invoke the function using the Portal's Run command it executes correctly.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure function gives "The 'code' query parameter provided in the HTTP request did not match the expected value."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41261343/azure-function-gives-the-code-query-parameter-provided-in-the-http-request-di)

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/functionschallenge/issues/21  -- Issue is discussed here to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I use Restlet Client for any API work and it seems it has a strange issue.  I copied the default (Host Key) from the Portal and pasted the URL into the Restlet Client and for some reason the last '==' of the code parameter is dropped.  I tried the request using Postman and that request worked!

Thanks for all of the comments and the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Which key did you choose to authenticate your request? There are 3 types of keys. Please choose the default(Function key) and use the generated URL and the key. I tested it on my side and the function key could pass the validation from server.

[image]

For more information of function key and host key, link below is for your reference.

[Azure Function WebHook API Keys](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Http-Functions#api-keys)